# Ajax retornando HTML junto com JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

O código que fiz estava funcionando normalmente mas de repente, passou a se comportar de maneira diferente. Já fiz todos os debugs possíveis, deem uma olhada

```
$( function(){
    // When submit it
    $('.frms').not('#form-newsletter').on('submit', function(){
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.submit').on('click', function(e){
        var id_form = $(this).parents('.frms').attr('id'),
            data = $('#' + id_form).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: './ajax/submit.php',
            data: data,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#' + id_form).find('.loading').fadeIn();
                $('#' + id_form + ' .submit').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
            },
            success: function(callback){
                if(callback.error){
                    $('.success').remove();
                    $('.error').remove();
                    var split = callback.error.split('#');

                    if(split[1] == 'show_message'){
                        $('body').append('<div class="error">' + split[0] + '</div>');
                    }else{
                        $('#' + id_form + ' #' + split[1]).focus();
                        $('#' + id_form + ' #' + split[1]).on('blur', function(){
                            if($(this) != ''){
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    $('.error').on('click',function(){
                        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
                    });
                }else{
                    $('.success').remove();
                    $('.error').remove();
                    split = callback.success.split('#');

                    if(split[1] == 'success'){
                        $('#' + id_form).find('input[class!="noclear"]').val('');
                        $('#' + id_form).find('textarea').val('');
                        $('#' + id_form).find('select').val('');
                        $('body').append('<div class="success">' + split[0] + '</div>');
                    }else if(split[1] == 'redirecty'){
                        $('body').append('<div class="success">' + split[0] + '</div>');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            window.location.href = 'my-account';
                        },2000);
                    }
                    $('.success').on('click',function(){
                        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
                    });
                }
            },

            complete: function(){
                $('#' + id_form).find('.loading').fadeOut();
                $('#' + id_form + ' .submit').removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

E na página `submit.php` que recebe os dados ela devolve o output:

```
if(!empty($message)):
    echo json_encode($message);
endif;
```

Isso era ok até o script passar a enviar junto com o Json a página html completa.

Alguma sugestão do que pode estar causando esse problema?

Comment: O problema é no javascript ou no php?

Comment: `Isso era ok até`.. o que quer dizer com isso? Quer dizer que até certo ponto funcionava e depois de um dado momento começou o problema? Basta retroceder até o ponto onde funcionava e analisar quais alterações posteriores podem ser a causa do problema.

Comment: Cadê o HTML?...

Comment: Gente, o HTML acredito não ser importante porque é dinâmico. O problema é ou no js ou na resposta do servidor. Conseguem identificar algo errado? Já debuguei com todas as opções que tenho, já isolei a parte do script da página que está solicitando pra ver se era esse o problema, mas nada. A página submit.php, que é a que recebe os dados, após todo o tratamento dos dados ela responde com $message = ['error' => 'message_callback.#show_message']; if(!empty($message)): echo json_encode($message); endif;

Comment: Não consigo identificar de onde está vindo esse HTML. A messagem está sendo enviada corretamente, porém acima vem o HTML completo da página que não deveria vir.

Comment: @SamuelDosSantos Faça um teste bem mínimo para isolar o problema. Seu código está cheio de coisas desnecessárias.

Comment: Troca `json` por `jsonp`em `dataType`.

Comment: Vou realizar novos testes com base nas sugestão e posto o resultado.

Comment: Coloque um `console.log(callback)` logo apos a função de sucesso e abra o console do navegador para verificar como o PHP está retornando a resposta. Ela deve ser JSON puro, não pode ter nenhum tipo de HTML ou texto fora da estrutura do JSON, se não o jQuery não vai reconhecer e vai acontecer o erro.